# Linux Screen for session management in PuTTY

Tags: linux, bash, putty, gnu-screen

I am connecting to a Linux system via PuTTY. I am using GNU screen.

Once I input a command on the screen, I am unable to create a new one or do anything else until this command gets completed. I have a feeling I am going about this all wrong.

When it says <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>C</kbd>, what does this mean? How do I get those keys listed on *[How To Use Linux Screen](http://www.rackaid.com/resources/linux-screen-tutorial-and-how-to/)*?

I am currently having to create multiple sessions of PuTTY.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Once you have executed the command `screen` you're now in a screen session. You can create new windows (think of them like tabs) and switch between them. To create a window, you use the command <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>c</kbd>. This means:

- Hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>a</kbd> simultaneously (this tells screen you'd like to issue it the following command...)
- Release the keys
- Press <kbd>c</kbd> (create new window button)

This should create a new window in the screen session (you now have two).

To switch between windows you, again, use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> command followed by the number of the window you'd like to switch to. E.g., <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd> will take you home.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>"</kbd> will list the windows you have active.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>k</kbd> closes the current active window.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>d</kbd> "Detaches" the screen session, you are moved back to the terminal where you invoked `screen`. Your screen session is still running in a background process, to return to it use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>x</kbd>.

Comment: It seems most of these commands are not working on my PuTTy. Or maybe they are disabled. The only thing that works is CTRL-A d

Comment: Invoke `screen`, and then type `echo Screen 0!`, add another window as in the answer and your text `Screen 0!` should have vanished as you're in a new window. Try switching back to window 0 and it should be there :).

Comment: After quiting you screen add the following line to your ~/.screenrc `hardstatus alwayslastline "Host %H %l|%Y-%m-%d %c|%w"` and start screen again. This configuration line will setup a status line with some usefull information. With that, you are able to see newely created windows. With CTRL+A CTRL+A you switch between the last two windows back and forth.